# XtraReport is displaying multiple pages in multiple column mode

Tags: c#, devexpress, report, xtrareport

I've a DevExpress XtraReport that displays a 100 page report. I want the pages to be displayed in a way pages are displayed in MS-Word. But, the XtraReport displays them in a multiple column/row mode (Card Layout). Is there any property other than setting the MultiColumn property to None that can help me overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, DevExpress XtraReports provide only one way to implement [the multi-column layout](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument2601). If you are searching the solution for making a report with a multi-column text, you can track these suggestions:

- [XRRichText - Multiple columns](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/S134365.aspx)
- [Page Builder - Multicolumn - Ability to wrap large text to next column on a page](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Issues/ViewIssue.aspx?issueid=A1271)